# ssh persistent sessions with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, ssh

I am working with node.js, and I am trying to embed a console in the web browser to work in a remote server. The web application do the connection so the user does not need to do the `ssh username@host` but only type commands.

I have tried the node.js' `ssh2` module and other modules which use ssh2. But I'm experiencing always the same problem. Every time I execute a command programmatically using `exec()`, the ssh session is restarted. I'll explain it better with an example.

```
> ls
```

returns the content of home directory, one of the directories in the home directory is `mydir`

```
> cd mydir
> ls
```

returns the content of my home directory again, because after a command is executed the ssh session is closed/restarted.

Any node.js library which can do the job? or even a library of other technology different to javascript?

**Edit:** Other example for clarifying, using the node.js' module `ssh-exec`
The server has to execute some commands in other machine using ssh. A function in the server contains the following code

```
var c = exec.connection('username@host.com'); // It takes the ssh key from the default location
exec('cd mydir', c).pipe(process.stdout);
exec('ls -lh', c).pipe(process.stdout);
```

As you can see I am not ending the connection after the first `exec` but the output I obtain is the content of the home directory not the content of mydir directory, because the ssh session is reset after each `exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maintainer of node.js' ssh2 module provided the solution.

To use the method `shell()` instead of the method `exec()`.

The method `shell()` creates an interactive session with the server we are connecting.
The method `shell()` provides a stream as a parameter of its callback (like the method `exec()`).

Like when using `exec()`, `stream.on('data', function(data, extended) {...});` can be used to get the output of the commands. However, in this case, to provide commands (input) to the machine you connected with, you need to use `stream.write(yourcommand+'\n');`

PS. Feel free to edit to improve the accuracy of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess a bit, but you do something like `child = exec('ssh username@host ls')`?

You can do something like

```
child = exec('ssh username@host');
```

upfront and in the "loop" of your browser

```
child.stdin.write('ls\n');
```

When finished, just close `stdin`:

```
child.stdin.end()
```

which also finishes the child process.

Comment: It's not like that. I use ajax, to call a function in the server which takes a shh connection previously created and do `connection.exec('cd mydir')`. Later, other ajax request calls the function with other command; the function executes the command doing `connection.exec('ls')`. I don't have problems with the output, and getting it and printing it fine, but the output is not the expected one (it is not the content of mydir, but the content of home directory) because the ssh session seems to be reseted after each exec :(

Comment: Does not change much. You still have a new context with your exec-calls. You need to open on server side the ssh connection and keep it open (and idle timeout if you want).

Comment: What I am trying to explain is that that doesn't work. If I open a connection in the server side and programmatically, immediately after, I do `connection.exec('cd mydir')` and immediately I do `connection.exec('ls')` the result is not expected because the connection seems to be reset after each exec. I'll edit my question to clarify with an example.

Comment: Problem is not the connection, but the exec... What type is this connection?

Comment: Well then - see answer from David T. That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this link is old but I figured this may help someone if they're looking for a solution. The

> To use the method shell() instead of the method exec().

Works. Here's another solution. Use absolute file paths i.e.

```
conn.exec("mkdir -p /home/user/Direc/{one,two,three}/", function(err, stream) {
        if (err) throw err;
        stream.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
        }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
        });
    });

conn.exec("ls -la /home/user/", function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
        console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
        conn.end();
    }).on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
    }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
    });
});
```