# how to reuse SSH connection between different SFTP transmission in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssh, sftp

I know the `ssh2` package and it's example is straightforward enough. but I dont want to reconnect server every time, have any ideas?

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Client :: ready');
  conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
    if (err) throw err;
    sftp.readdir('foo', function(err, list) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.dir(list);
      conn.end();
    });
  });
}).connect({
  host: '192.168.100.100',
  port: 22,
  username: 'frylock',
  password: 'nodejsrules'
});
```

Comment: See if the solution mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453748/ssh-persistent-sessions-with-node-js - solves your issue

Comment: @vimal-mahi thanks, but I want to combine it with sftp

Comment: There is an autoReconnect option in [promise-sftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-sftp). Not sure if that helps you though. Have a look please.